# SQL: Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been having a lot of problems in creating a new Oracle table. It has gone from one error to another.

This may be its last issue.

I am trying out why this table is giving the error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis:

```
CREATE TABLE rental
    ( rental_id        CHAR(8)
    , overdue_cost     INTEGER(10,2)
    , days_checked_out INTEGER(10,0)
    )
```

Comment: I use the same syntax throughout my other tables. Are you saying they do not work?

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find the `integer(10,2)` syntax? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020

Comment: It is provided to me by the schools course supplement text. But not that I look over it. I read it wrong. It says number not integer. So I used the wrong name the entire time without knowing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle `INTEGER` type does not allow either `precision` nor `scale`.
Actually, Oracle's `INTEGER` is basically the same as `NUMBER(38, 0)`.

In your case you can change the definition of `overdue_cost` and `days_checked_out` in two ways:

1. Define them as `INTEGERS`, but leave the `presision`/`scale` out:

   ```
   overdue_cost     INTEGER,    
   days_checked_out INTEGER
   ```
2. Define them as `NUMBER(10, 0)` - preferred, since one of the fields has non-zero `scale`.

   ```
   overdue_cost     NUMBER(10, 0),    
   days_checked_out NUMBER(10, 2)
   ```

Comment: Yeah, my bad. In fact `INTEGER` does not allow for precission either. Edited my answer. You can try your code on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4bf16).

Comment: Now that seems to have made a difference