# SQL Table Error: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
    STUDENT_NAME CHAR(20),
    FATHER_NAME CHAR(20),
    ENROLL_NO INT(12),
    PHONE_NO INT(12),
    EMAIL_ID CHAR(20),
    ADDRESS CHAR(20),
    COURSE CHAR(20),
    D_O_B DATE,
);
```

My above table showing this error

> Error report -
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

I am not able to understand which right parenthesis is missing.

Comment: There is a `,` after the last column... does mysql allow this?

Comment: This is small mistakes, should run the code on any online editor and you should be sure you don't ask here for syntax error. online editor ex : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Missing right parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018810/sql-missing-right-parenthesis)

Comment: That's an oracle error not mysql.

Comment: Havel also a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417845/what-is-the-major-difference-between-varchar2-and-char/20418849#20418849

Answer (score 2):

Just remove tha comma (`,`) from last line

This is your correct code (MySQL)

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
      STUDENT_NAME CHAR(20),
      FATHER_NAME CHAR(20),
      ENROLL_NO INT(12),
      PHONE_NO INT(12),
      EMAIL_ID CHAR(20),
      ADDRESS CHAR(20),
      COURSE CHAR(20),
      D_O_B DATE
);
```

**Update ::** `INT` is not supported by oracle. user `NUMBER` data type instead.

This is the updated code of oracle

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_TABLE
(
  STUDENT_NAME CHAR(20),
  FATHER_NAME CHAR(20),
  ENROLL_NO NUMBER(10),
  PHONE_NO NUMBER(10),
  EMAIL_ID VARCHAR(20),
  ADDRESS VARCHAR(20),
  COURSE VARCHAR(20),
  D_O_B DATE
);
```

Comment: Its still showing error. Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
      STUDENT_NAME CHAR(20),
      FATHER_NAME CHAR(20),
      ENROLL_NO INT(12),
      PHONE_NO INT(12),
      EMAIL_ID CHAR(20),
      ADDRESS CHAR(20),
      COURSE CHAR(20),
      D_O_B DATE
)
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: You copy my exact code, its working. check this link - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed7fef

Comment: The error is oracle and fails in sqlfiddle when set to oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this on my end.It works for me.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_TABLE
(
  STUDENT_NAME CHAR(20),
  FATHER_NAME CHAR(20),
  ENROLL_NO NUMBER(10),
  PHONE_NO NUMBER(10),
  EMAIL_ID VARCHAR(20),
  ADDRESS VARCHAR(20),
  COURSE VARCHAR(20),
  D_O_B DATE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle? Get rid of CHAR and VARCHAR datatypes and use **VARCHAR2** instead.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE STUDENT
  2    ( STUDENT_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  3      FATHER_NAME  VARCHAR2(20),
  4      ENROLL_NO    NUMBER(12),
  5      PHONE_NO     NUMBER(12),
  6      EMAIL_ID     VARCHAR2(20),
  7      ADDRESS      VARCHAR2(20),
  8      COURSE       VARCHAR2(20),
  9      D_O_B        DATE
 10  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Apart from that, that table doesn't have a **primary key** defined and - in my opinion - it should. A few `NOT NULL` constraints (for example, on STUDENT_NAME) might be a good choice.

On a second thought, why STUDENT_NAME? It isn't **normalized** - should be split to (at least) STUDENT_FIRST_NAME and STUDENT_LAST_NAME.

Someone (@Vikash, who posted a message 3 hours ago)) said that Oracle doesn't support `INT` datatype; well, it does, but you'd rather use NUMBER:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (phone_no int);

Table created.
```

but you can't set its precision:

```
SQL> create table test_2
  2    (phone_no int(12));
  (phone_no int(12))
               *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL>
```

so - in your code - use either `INT` or `NUMBER(12)`, but beware of *unexpected* traps (i.e. rounding), such as

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (num1 int,
  3     num2 number(12));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (123.456, 123.456);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

      NUM1       NUM2
---------- ----------
       123        123

SQL>
```